# Windows DLL unexpectedly loading more than once in the same application

Tags: windows, dll, c++-cli

A program I wrote (in C#) accesses through a C++/CLI wrapper library a native (c++) library I also wrote.

I noticed that the native library's DllMain method is called more than once, and the debugger thinks that multiple memory locations are connected to some of the library calls. From what I see, the library is initialized (and memory allocated) more than once.

Given that my code does not use functions such as LoadLibrary, and the dll is used including the library's .h files and .lib, why is it initialized more than once, and what can I do to avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK DLL may not be loaded more than once into the same address space. Even if you call `LoadLibrary` explicitly the DLL won't be loaded more than once, instead its reference counter is incremented.

Also I don't understand exactly what you mean by "*debugger thinks that multiple memory locations are connected to some of the library calls*". A single imported symbol (function or a variable address) is filled by just one address during DLL binding.

I believe you have one of the following:

- You may load simultaneously multiple versions of the same library (several DLL files). A typical error is to load debug and release DLL versions simultaneously.
- Your `DllMain` is called several times, but it does not mean it's loaded several times. Do you check the parameters supplied to the `DllMain`? Is it `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`, or perhaps it's just `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH/DLL_THREAD_DETACH`?

Comment: By "debugger thinks that multiple memory locations are connected to some of the library calls" I refer to a strange fact I observed: using Visual Studio's system to move the execution cursor (the function which allows you to choose a program line to execute next) I noticed that when moving the cursor on some function calls Visual Studio asked me to specify which version of the same function I should move to, giving a list of three copies of the library with different addresses. The function itself is not overloaded or polymorph in any way.

Comment: @Coffee on Mars: Oh, I see. If you're 100% sure it's not a template function or what-or-ever, then I believe it's probably multiple DLL versions loaded at once.

Comment: I finally managed to work on the problem again, and it seems that the multiple calls were due to the thread/process attach. The problems were apparently due to multiple calling threads.

Answer (score 1):

A DLL's entry point is called when it is first loaded into the process, as well as when any thread in the process is started or stopped.

If this is causing problem's in your DLLMain, then you need to [check the reason for DLL entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and handle appropriately.